# No output produced for C# Console Application on 'Start without Debugging'

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

When attempting to run a C# console application without the debugger (ie `Ctrl+F5`) no output appears in the terminal.
When run with the debugger (ie just `F5`), program executes as expected.

I made a quick test project to make sure it wasn't just my project:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Run with the debugger, "Test" is output to console, without it, nothing.
I don't know what I've changed, because (my original) programme was running fine without the debugger before now

Comment: `Console.ReadKey();` what happens if you change this line to `Console.Read();`

Comment: There have been a few other posts like this recently. Most people seem to blaming avast. Have you got it installed by any chance?

Comment: I do have avast...console window appears and sits there quite happily, but nothing appears in it...how is this a thing!?

Comment: Same behaviour in `ReadKey()` and `Read()` (other than how the two functions vary in and of themselves)

Comment: @LeftRight92 do you understand the code that you have posted.. what do you think Console.Read, or Console.ReadLine, or Console.ReadKey will do..? it will pause the command line window until user types in something ..

Comment: F5 starts a process with the name app.vshost.exe while CTRL + F5 will start app.exe. That's why, +1 @DarrenGourley

Comment: Agree with @DarrenGourley. Code itself should work just fine.

Comment: I tested your existing code and it works just fine @LeftRight92 not sure what you are expecting..

Comment: Unless the OP did not play with the Build & Run settings, On Run, never build, on build error - Launch old version etc..

Comment: It's a fresh project/solution so haven't tweaked any of the settings, all at default.

Comment: voting to close this question I think that the OP is not familiar with how to use the Debugger and Build Options etc...

Comment: @MethodMan It's not so much that as the fact that something in the way visual studio runs has changed without my intervention. Post above suggests it's avast interfering somehow.

Comment: Can confirm, it is avast doing something. Turning off the File System Shield seems to work around it.

Comment: @LeftRight92 You should post that as an answer so that people in the future will be able to benefit from this. Comments can be erased at any time but answers are more permanent.

Comment: @Tophandour Will do, although I'd imagine avast will fix their mistake sometime in the next week.

Comment: @LeftRight92 That's a good point. Maybe mentioning Visual Studio versions and Avast versions would help as well, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was found to be Avast preventing the executable from running properly. Temporarily disabling the File System Shield acts as a workaround.

Visual Studio 14.0.23107.0 D14REL

Avast 10.4.2233 (virus definition version: 151130-0)